# M-TIP18 Test 01 scenario 01

Tags: emv, mastercard

I'm working on the M-TIP - EMVCo L3 build 280 certification and on Test case 18 01 01

I keep receiving an error on the second generation of AC, the terminal keeps requesting the TC instead of AAC when the issuer responded with response 85,

I just need to know if there's any solution I can do on the ATM to fix this issue.

The ATM is Diebold Nixdorf WIN10

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's definitively not a Stack Overflow question, but I'll try to help you anyway.

RC85 is a 'Not decline' type of answer and it might be a matter of type of transaction whether it is considered an acceptance which might be confusing in some situations. This is a logical result of the transaction but terminal-card interface do not always reflect it as there is a differentiation between fully EMV financial transactions and those not defined by EMV. Transactions that consider RC85 as accepted are not defined by EMV specification and should result in AAC regardless of the the logical result.

You don't mention what type of application is running on your ATM, what host you are interfacing and what protocol is used for that. If you are using NDC/DDC, you should first look at your host and download to see if AAC is really what is expected (in my experience, this case is rarely covered correctly in first run). If you have certainty you have it right on the host side or you are using thick client application that handles that logic internally on device side, try talking to your ATM application vendor.